# Switching from MSVC14 to MSVC16 leads to "compiler is out of heap space (C1060)" error

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to switch from the `Visual Studio 14 2015` compiler to `Visual Studio 16 2019` to compile my project (also tried `Visual Studio 15 2017`, but that resulted in the same issues). I'm using [irrequietus/typestring](https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring), which worked perfectly fine with the old compiler but leads to errors now.

Here's a class that's supposed to be used with a typestring:

```cpp
// my_custom_class.h
template<typename T>
class MyCustomClass
{
public:
  static bool compareTheTypestring(const std::string& other) const {
    return std::strcmp(data(), other.c_str()) == 0;
  }
}
```

This is how I use the class:

```cpp
// use_it.cpp
#include "typestring.hh"
#include "my_custom_class.h"
typedef MyCustomClass<typestring_is("Foo")> FooCompare;
```

Which spits out the following error in `typestring.hh`:

- `compiler is out of heap space (C1060)`.

And more errors in `use_it.cpp`:

- `irqus::typeek: no matching overloaded function found (C2672)`
- `Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type irqus::typeek(irqus::typestring<C...>)'`
- cannot deduce template arguments for `MyCustomClass`

The repository contains a similar issue, but the maintainer doesn't seem to reply. I tried to find alternative typestring implementations, but couldn't. Can anyone help me to resolve this, please?

Comment: For starters a static member function may not have the qualifier const.

Comment: please give a [mcve].

Comment: Ah I get it... you want to use strings as template arguments. Are you /sure/ that is the best solution for your problem? I mean, there are millions of C++ programmers, and the fact that this is not part of the library or there is a good up-to-date third party library must indicate something.... Maybe explain /why/ you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue has already been reported in january](https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring/issues/6), with 0 responses since then. It seems the library is no longer being updated... maybe look for an alternative solution

You should really add the details of what you are trying to do into your question. Has to read through the external library before I understood what it is you are trying to achieve. My best suggestion would be: look for an alternative. There are other ways for compile-time strings. Template arguments are probably not the best answer.

If you *really* want to use the template argument strings, you'll have to fix it yourself. The library was probably relying on undefined behavior. So it's broken now.
I was trying it, but it's not very straight forward. You'll probably need to use the [charizing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/charizing-operator-hash-at?view=vs-2019) in macro's to split the string, and then put the chars into a tuple-type...

```
template<char c>
class CharType {
public:
    static constexpr char Char = c;
};

using FooString = std::tuple<CharType<'F'>, CharType<'o'>, CharType<'o'>>;
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look at the charizing operator, maybe that's what I'm looking for. Otherwise, you might be right: maybe there is a better option to do what I'm trying to do.